# CRS transform from EPSG 4326 (WGS 84) ? to EPSG 27700 (OSGB 1936 / British National Grid)

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, pgadmin-3

I have a table which is an import of a shp file from www.geofabrik.de/ England > Roads.

I've tried to change the CRS to EPSG 27700 but when I add this back to QGIS along side other layers which are EPSG  27700 (OSGB 1936 / British National Grid) it isn't correct / near these.

I've been using, which runs, but doesn't correct the issue.

```
UPDATE public.roads_eng SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,4326), 27700);

ALTER TABLE public.roads_eng ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 27700);
```

[image: Road_Screenshot]
[image: Table_code]

Comment: Are you sure that data is in 4326?

Comment: @iant It's OpenStreet Maps and that uses WGS 84 so I thought so?

Comment: The roads.prj file I just got from there seems to be epsg:4326, so that seems right. What's the bounding box of your PG roads layer? Note OSM also uses 3857 (web mercator) but I've not got that.

Comment: @Spacedman the other layers are from the ONS open geography portal so just boundaries, all of which are OSGB 1936 (27700). So on transformation the roads should sit nicely in there.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm a bit unclear about your line: "I've been using, which runs, but doesn't create the issue". What *does* create the issue?

Comment: @Spacedman typo, sorry, correct the issue*, could it be something to do with when its added to imported in to Postgres from the vector import tool maybe? Or shouldn't that matter if I'm using the above syntax to change the CRS?

Comment: If you could post a sample of the data it would help. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with what you are doing, but it isn't correct/near these isn't very helpful for anyone trying to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JohnBarça Added some screenshots to the original post, just added an a map quest osm layer to see where the road layer was going despite being the CRS being 27700, circled, off the cost of cornwall.

Comment: That's close to (0,0) - that would happen if the layer still has degrees in its geometry but has an epsg:27700 label - because nothing could be further from +- 180metres from the 0,0 origin... What does the bounding box say?

Comment: Sorry i'm a novice, bounding box?

Comment: The "bounding box" or "extent" is the min and max of the x and y coordinates. In QGIS, the "metadata" tab (of the dialog in your screenshot) has a "Properties" section which has the "Extent" in "layer spatial reference system units". If that looks like its degrees then you haven't transformed the coordinates.

Comment: @Spacedman 

Extents
In layer spatial reference system units

xMin,yMin -5.46939,49.9291 : xMax,yMax 1.79222,55.8092

Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: The extent is in degrees, so you better set EPSG:4326 as CRS for that.

Comment: @AndreJ  shouldn't the code correct this though?  UPDATE public.roads_eng SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,4326), 27700);  ALTER TABLE public.roads_eng ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 27700);j

Comment: I am no expert on SQL, but have you tried the syntax from http://postgis.net/2013/08/30/tip_ST_Set_or_Transform/ ?

Comment: @AndreJ  Thanks, thats it.

  ALTER TABLE public.roads_sco 

  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 27700) 

  USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,4326),27700);

Answer (score 3):

Solved, thanks.

Needed to being ST_Transform instead of ST_SetSRID (see last comment / link)

```
ALTER TABLE public.roads_sco ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 27700) USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,4326),27700)
```